# adding a for into a tab using extjs

Tags: extjs

Kindly let me know how to add a form to a dynamically created tab in ExtJS??????????

Answer (score 0):

```
myTab.add(myForm);
myTab.doLayout();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var tabpanel = new Ext.TabPanel({
  activeTab: 0,
  layoutOnTabChange: true,
  items: [{
    title: "A tab"
  }]
});

var new_tab = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
  title: "A form",
  closable: true
});

tabpanel.add(new_tab);
```

Take a look at the examples though.